# How to check that the string is email?

Tags: python, regex, email

I use the following code currently:

```
regexp = re.compile(r'[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}', re.IGNORECASE)
email = regexp.findall(stext)
if email:
    email = email[0]
```

But it will work even when `stext` contains some other text as well besides e-mail (for ex., `some text email@example.com some other text`). When I would like to check if `stext` contains `email@example.com` **only** (ok, probably with leading or/and trailing spaces, no other characters).

PS. I also think that probably I should use `mail.is_email_valid` instead of regex, it [will allow](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/mail.py?spec=svn257&r=257#212) me to support long domains like `.museam` or local domains like `.рф`.

Comment: You can use the `^` and `$` special characters to match the beginning and end of a string, respectively.  Something like `r'^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$'` would get you started.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add ^ in the start which means "text begins here" and $ in the end which is "no more text after here".

That would give:

`r'^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$'`

Comment: Doesn't account for "ok, probably with leading or/and trailing spaces, no other characters"... adding '\s*' after ^ and before $ would be better.

Comment: Good idea, it's not a valid e-mail though with spaces. Maybe trimming the user input before doing anything with it is better. That would also account for saving e-mails with spaces in your database for example

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression :

```
\s?[A-Z0-9_-+%]+@[A-Z0-9_-+%]+\.[A-Z0-9]\s?
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use \b for word boundary before and after the email?